# Как сделать корректнй вывод утилиты tree

Tags: алгоритм, golang, дерево

Задача сделать читаемый вывод прграммы tree. Вывод должен быть таким же как в ситемной утилите tree в linux.
У меня есть код, который получает дерево, но не получается сделать правильные отступы чтобы показать вложенность одного фала/папки в другой.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    GetDirs(".")
}

func GetDirs(pwd string) {
    filepath.Walk(pwd, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) (ok error) {
        if info.IsDir() {
            fmt.Println(path)
            pwd = path
            GetFiles(pwd)
        }
        return ok
    })
}

func GetFiles(pwd string) {
    files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(pwd)
    for _, file := range files {
        if !file.IsDir() {
            fmt.Println("\t|__", file.Name())
        }
    }
}
```

С помощью приведенного кода я получаю путь и файлы в этом пути. Но директории, независимо от того в какую директорию они вложены, все на одном уровне выводятся. Как сделать чтобы вложенность была ясна в выводе?
Приложу пример вывода tree встроенной в линукс. Нужно так же.

```
/home/user/goprogs
├── anonfunc
│   └── anon.go
├── arriter
│   ├── arit.go
│   ├── __debug_bin
│   └── nwefolder
├── async
│   └── main.go
├── channels
│   └── main.go
├── defer
│   └── defer.go
├── from
│   ├── functions
│   │   └── publ.go
│   └── main.go
├── goroutunes
│   └── main.go
├── hell
│   ├── hell.go
│   └── workspace.code-workspace
├── hz
│   └── main.go
├── intrfcs
│   └── main.go
├── intrfcs(r)
│   └── main.go
├── main.go
├── map
│   └── main.go
├── marshall\unmarshall
│   └── main.go
├── multi
│   └── main.go
├── obinob
│   └── main.go
├── Screenshot_20210212-175610_DuckDuckGo.jpg
├── self
│   ├── intrfcs
│   │   └── main.go
│   └── tree
│       ├── dir1
│       │   ├── asdfa
│       │   ├── asdgghh
│       │   └── dir4
│       │       ├── dir5
│       │       │   ├── dkjhf
│       │       │   └── ksdhhhh
│       │       ├── test
│       │       └── test1
│       ├── dir2
│       │   ├── dir3
│       │   │   ├── lfj
│       │   │   ├── wwee
│       │   │   └── yytt
│       │   └── ttyy
│       └── main.go
├── struct
│   └── structure.go
├── struct(r)
│   └── main.go
├── test
│   └── test.go
├── timers
│   ├── main.go
│   └── туц ащдвук
└── web
    └── web.go
```

Answer (score 1):

идея в том, что в каждом из функций нужно знать как печатать. также если зашли уже внутрь GetFiles, то нужно печатать и ее содержимое папок. поэтому нужно обратно вызвать GetDirs.

прикладываю неполноценное решение. чтобы оно было в точности как у tree, то нужно сначала печатать файлы, потом только папки. поэтому внутри filepath.Walk сначала собираем все в кучу, после уже печатаем

p.s. originalPwd нужен только для того, чтобы обрезать пути от нужной до печатуемой

```
package test

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)
func Tree(pwd string) {
    GetDirs(pwd, pwd, "_")
}

func GetDirs(originalPwd, pwd, shift string) {
    filepath.Walk(pwd, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) (ok error) {
        if info.IsDir() {
            GetFiles(originalPwd, path, shift + "  ")
            fmt.Println("|" + strings.Repeat("-", len(shift)) + strings.Replace(path, originalPwd, "", -1))
        }
        return ok
    })
}

func GetFiles(originalPwd, pwd, shift string) {
    files, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(pwd)
    for _, file := range files {
        if file.IsDir() {
            GetDirs(originalPwd, pwd+ "/"+file.Name(), shift + " ")
        } else{
            fmt.Println("|" + strings.Repeat(" ", len(shift)) + "|__", file.Name())
        }
    }
}

func TestA(t *testing.T) {
    Tree("../questions")
}
```

вывод:

```
=== RUN   TestA
|      |__ docker-compose.yaml
|         |__ test.go
|-------/1139325/jsonb
|      |__ main.go
|         |__ main_test.go
|         |__ tw_test.go
|-------/1139325/test
|----/1139325
|      |__ test.go
|----/1139325/jsonb
|      |__ main_test.go
|      |__ tw_test.go
|----/1139325/test
|         |__ api.go
|            |__ config_api.go
|----------/jbrains/restapi/operations
|         |__ server_error.go
|-------/jbrains/restapi
|         |__ config_api.go
|-------/jbrains/restapi/operations
|----/jbrains
|      |__ api.go
|         |__ config_api.go
|-------/jbrains/restapi/operations
|      |__ server_error.go
|----/jbrains/restapi
|      |__ config_api.go
|----/jbrains/restapi/operations
|      |__ questions1237157.go
|----/main
|      |__ test_test.go
|      |__ variation_test.go
|----/ser
|      |__ t_test.go
|----/test
|      |__ a.png
|      |__ b.png
|      |__ main.go
|----/ui
|      |__ a.png
|      |__ b.png
|      |__ j.json
|      |__ main.go
|----/ui2
|-
|   |__ docker-compose.yaml
|      |__ test.go
|----/1139325/jsonb
|   |__ main.go
|      |__ main_test.go
|      |__ tw_test.go
|----/1139325/test
|-/1139325
|   |__ test.go
|-/1139325/jsonb
|   |__ main_test.go
|   |__ tw_test.go
|-/1139325/test
|      |__ api.go
|         |__ config_api.go
|-------/jbrains/restapi/operations
|      |__ server_error.go
|----/jbrains/restapi
|      |__ config_api.go
|----/jbrains/restapi/operations
|-/jbrains
|   |__ api.go
|      |__ config_api.go
|----/jbrains/restapi/operations
|   |__ server_error.go
|-/jbrains/restapi
|   |__ config_api.go
|-/jbrains/restapi/operations
|   |__ questions1237157.go
|-/main
|   |__ test_test.go
|   |__ variation_test.go
|-/ser
|   |__ t_test.go
|-/test
|   |__ a.png
|   |__ b.png
|   |__ main.go
|-/ui
|   |__ a.png
|   |__ b.png
|   |__ j.json
|   |__ main.go
|-/ui2
--- PASS: TestA (0.01s)
```

Comment: Сегодня попробую. Если сработает ответ помечу и буду тогда работать с этим дальше)